# Is this a bug with Meson using static libs on Mac

Tags: macos, static-libraries, meson-build

Using meson 0.64.1 on a Mac, having problem using static libs installed by Homebrew.

This line -

```
iconv_lib_dep = c_compiler.find_library('iconv', dirs: cross_lib_path, static: true)
```

gives "ERROR: C static library 'libiconv' not found", even though libiconv.a is sitting next to libiconv.dylib in the same folder, and it finds libiconv.dylib just fine without the "static: true". Another thing I tried got me this msg - "ERROR: '/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/libiconv.a' is not a static library." Are Homebrew installed .a files not static libraries?

This line -

```
  iconv_lib_dep = c_compiler.find_library('/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib/libiconv', static: true)
```

gives no error, but then building gets Undefined symbols link errors for, e.g. "_iconv_close". Using hex editor, I see neither libiconv.dylib nor libiconv.a contain string "_iconv_close", but both contain "_libiconv_close". Am I doing something wrong? or is there a bug in the Mac version of meson?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the problem using c_compiler.find_library() to find static libraries is to use dependency() instead. For a long more detailed answer, see the meson bug report https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/11237